# Django's queryset.aggregate max() runs into issues after 9

Tags: python, django

I am running into an issue with the queryset.aggregate(max()) function in Django when the field I am querying has values larger than 9.

I have a model named `Build` and I want to query this model to get the largest value in the `BuildIdentifier`field.
The code below works perfectly when the values in `BuildIdentifier` are less than 10. As soon as I have a value greater than 10, it will still only return 9.
What am I missing here? I am only dealing with integers.

```
previousBuild = Build.objects.filter(author = currentAuthor)
largestIdDict = previousBuild.aggregate(Max('BuildIdentifier'))
largestIdList = list(largestIdDict.values())
largestIdNo = largestIdList[0]
```

`LargestIdNo` returns the correct value up until a value greater than 9 is added to the `BuildIdentifier` field, then it just keeps returning 9, even though there is definitely larger values in this field

Comment: This looks like an issues of sorting strings vs integers. Are you sure that `BuildIdentifier` is a `models.IntegerField`? can you post the `Build` model code?

Comment: Ahh, it's a Charfield. I will change this and hopefully not blow up too much. will report back shortly and let you know if that worked out. Thanks!

Comment: That did it. Thanks @azundo !